# Double scrollbar with no iframe appearing on certain browsers

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I need help removing the double scrollbars that are appearing before I go insane!

I've tried searching for how to fix the double scroll bars appearing and have found  overflow:hidden  however I must not be adding it to the right areas because it's not fixing my issue. Any help would be greatly appreciated. There is no iframe. The code I am using is from a template udesign for wordpress, there are code snippets from http://www.universallyacclaimed.com/wp-themes/u-design/home-page-2/

Active Webpage with issue
https://www.cprtrainingpro.com/trial-alexis/

Wordpress page html/snippets

```html
[content_block class="sliderhomepage" bg_image="https://www.cprtrainingpro.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/front_page_header_slider.png" max_bg_width="yes" bg_fixed="yes" bg_position="center center" bg_repeat="no-repeat" parallax_scroll="yes" content_padding="100px 0 25px" font_color="#FFFFFF"]


[one_half]
    <div id="responsive" style="text-align: center; padding-bottom:100px; overflow: hidden;">
        <h4 style="margin-bottom: 0px;" class="headertop1"><span style="font-size: 70px; color: #FFFFFF; text-shadow: 2px 2px 8px #000; font-weight:bold;">Onsite Training</h4>
        <h5 style="margin: 0px; padding:0px;"><span style="font-size: 30px; color: #FFFFFF; text-shadow: 2px 2px 8px #000; font-weight:100;">Workplace & Group Classes</span></h5>
   
    [flat_button text="SCHEDULE A CLASS" title="" "url="#" padding="15px 25px" bg_color="rgba(255,255,255,0.85)" border_color="#FFFFFF" border_width="1px" text_color="#d80000" text_size="20px" font-weight="800" align="center" target="_self"]</div>
   
[/one_half]


[one_half_last]
<div id="responsive" style="text-align: center; overflow: hidden;">
        <h4 style="margin-bottom: 0px;" class="headertop2"><span style="font-size: 70px; color: #FFFFFF; text-shadow: 2px 2px 8px #000; font-weight:bold;">Get Certified </h4>
        <h5 style="margin: 0px; padding:0px;"><span style="font-size: 30px; color: #FFFFFF; text-shadow: 2px 2px 8px #000; font-weight:100;">CPR & First Aid Classes</span></h5>
    </div>
    [flat_button text="FIND A CLASS" title="" url="https://www.cprtrainingpro.com/find-a-class/" padding="15px 25px" bg_color="rgba(255,255,255,0.85)" border_color="#FFFFFF" border_width="1px" text_color="#d80000" text_size="20px" font-weight="800" align="center" target="_self"]
    <!--<div style="text-align: center; margin-top: 55px;"> <a href="#more-features"><i class="fa fa-angle-down circle-wrap" style="color:#AAAAAA;font-size:1.5em;"></i></a></div>-->
[/one_half_last]
[/content_block]


[content_block content_padding="25px 0 50px"]
[one_fourth]
<div style="margin-top: 30px; overflow: hidden;">
            <div style="text-align: center; overflow: hidden;"><i class="fa fa-medkit circle-wrap" aria-hidden="true" style="color: #bbb; font-size: 2em;"><!-- icon --></i></div>
            <div style="text-align: center;">
                <h3><a title="CPR, AED & First Aid" href="#" target="_blank">CPR, AED & First Aid</a></h3>
                <p style="text-align: center;">Meets OSHA Requirements</p></div></div>
[flat_button text="REGISTER" title="" url="" padding="15px 25px" bg_color="#d80000" border_color="#FFFFFF" border_width="1px" text_color="#ffffff" text_size="15px" font-weight="800" align="center" target="_self"]
[/one_fourth]
[one_fourth]
<div style="margin-top: 30px;">
            <div style="text-align: center;">            <i class="fa fa-heartbeat circle-wrap" style="color: #bbb; font-size: 2em;"><!-- icon --></i></div>
            <div style="text-align: center;">
                <h3><a title="Visual Composer " href="http://codecanyon.net/item/visual-composer-page-builder-for-wordpress/242431" target="_blank">BLS - Basic Life Support</a></h3>
                <p style="text-align: center;">For Healthcare Providers</p></div></div>
[flat_button text="REGISTER" title="" url="" padding="15px 25px" bg_color="#d80000" border_color="#FFFFFF" border_width="1px" text_color="#ffffff" text_size="15px" font-weight="800" align="center" target="_self"]
[/one_fourth]
[one_fourth]
<div style="margin-top: 30px;">
            <div style="text-align: center;"><i class="fa fa-heart circle-wrap" style="color:#bbb; font-size:2em;"><!-- icon --></i></div>
            <div style="text-align: center;">
                <h3><a title="Visual Composer " href="http://codecanyon.net/item/visual-composer-page-builder-for-wordpress/242431" target="_blank">Pediatric First Aid & CPR</a></h3>
                <p style="text-align: center;">EMSA for Childcare Providers</p></div></div>
[flat_button text="REGISTER" title="" url="" padding="15px 25px" bg_color="#d80000" border_color="#FFFFFF" border_width="1px" text_color="#ffffff" text_size="15px" font-weight="800" align="center" target="_self"]
[/one_fourth]
[one_fourth_last]
<div style="margin-top: 30px;">
            <div style="text-align: center;"><i class="fa fa-id-card circle-wrap" style="color: #bbb; font-size: 2em;"><!-- icon --></i></div>
            <div style="text-align: center;">
                <h3><a title="Instructor Certification" href="#" target="_blank">Instructor Certification</a></h3>
                <p style="text-align: center;">CPR Instructor Classes</p></div></div>
[flat_button text="REGISTER" title="" url="" padding="15px 25px" bg_color="#d80000" border_color="#FFFFFF" border_width="1px" text_color="#ffffff" text_size="15px" font-weight="800" align="center" target="_self"]
[/one_fourth_last][/content_block]


[content_block bg_image="" max_bg_width="yes" bg_fixed="no" bg_position="top left" bg_size="contain" bg_repeat="repeat-x" parallax_scroll="no" bg_color="#f1f1f1" content_padding="50px 0px 50px" font_color="#bbb"]<h4 style="margin-bottom: 50px; padding-bottom:0; text-align:center;"><div class="mapheader1" style="font-size: 48px; color: #d80000; line-height: 1.2; font-weight: bold;">Southern California Training Centers</span></h4>
<div class="twothird">
[two_third]
<img src="https://www.cprtrainingpro.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/front_page_map_cpr.png" width="auto" height"auto" style="border:thin solid #ddd;">
[/two_third]</div>

<div class="onethirdlast">[one_third_last]

<!--<h3>Orange</h3><p><a href="https://www.google.com/maps/place/CPR+Training+Professionals/@33.8069517,-117.9272029,11z/data=!4m2!3m1!1s0x0:0x3ae56ddb1a1f49a7?hl=en-US" target="_blank">1717 W Orangewood Ave, Orange, CA 92686</a></p><div class="buttoncenter1 buttonleft1">[flat_button text="Directions" url="" padding="5px 10px" bg_color="#ffffff" border_color="#d80000" border_width="1px" text_color="#d80000" text_size="12px" font-weight="800" target="_self"][flat_button text="View Classes" url="" padding="5px 10px" bg_color="#d80000" border_color="#FFFFFF" border_width="1px"  text_color="#ffffff" text_size="12px" font-weight="800" target="_self"]</div><hr>-->

<h3>Orange</h3><p><a href="https://www.google.com/maps/place/CPR+Training+Professionals/@33.8069517,-117.9272029,11z/data=!4m2!3m1!1s0x0:0x3ae56ddb1a1f49a7?hl=en-US" target="_blank">1717 W Orangewood Ave, Orange, CA 92686</a></p><div class="mobilehideme">[flat_button text="Directions" url="" padding="5px 10px" bg_color="#ffffff" border_color="#d80000" border_width="1px" text_color="#d80000" text_size="12px" font-weight="800" target="_self"][flat_button text="View Classes" url="" padding="5px 10px" bg_color="#d80000" border_color="#FFFFFF" border_width="1px"  text_color="#ffffff" text_size="12px" font-weight="800" target="_self"]</div><hr class="hrmobile">

<h3>Irvine</h3><p><a href="https://www.google.com/maps/dir/''/110+Lamplighter,+Irvine,+CA+92620/@33.5259043,-117.6375619,10z/data=!4m8!4m7!1m0!1m5!1m1!1s0x80dcdcd9ce6ad36b:0x3ad84d9041470ea4!2m2!1d-117.7494133!2d33.6986096" target="_blank">110 Lamplighter, Irvine, CA 92620</a></p><div class="mobilehideme">[flat_button text="Directions" url="" padding="5px 10px" bg_color="#ffffff" border_color="#d80000" border_width="1px" text_color="#d80000" text_size="12px" font-weight="800" target="_self"][flat_button text="View Classes" url="" padding="5px 10px" bg_color="#d80000" border_color="#FFFFFF" border_width="1px"  text_color="#ffffff" text_size="12px" font-weight="800" target="_self"]</div><hr class="hrmobile">

<h3>Lake Forest</h3><p><a href="https://www.google.com/maps/place/Lake+Forest+Beach+and+Tennis+Club/@33.6303564,-117.7057278,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x80dce85a1867cb3f:0x22da80edf337db68!8m2!3d33.630352!4d-117.7035338" target="_blank">22921 Ridge Route Dr, Lake Forest, CA 92630</a></p><div class="mobilehideme">[flat_button text="Directions" url="" padding="5px 10px" bg_color="#ffffff" border_color="#d80000" border_width="1px" text_color="#d80000" text_size="12px" font-weight="800" target="_self"][flat_button text="View Classes" url="" padding="5px 10px" bg_color="#d80000" border_color="#FFFFFF" border_width="1px"  text_color="#ffffff" text_size="12px" font-weight="800" target="_self"]</div><hr class="hrmobile">

<h3>El Monte</h3><p><a href="https://www.google.com/maps/place/El+Monte+Aquatic+Center/@34.0667349,-118.0373265,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x80c2d0bb0cd2cd55:0x5f8b1416930b70b1!8m2!3d34.0667349!4d-118.0351378" target="_blank">11001 Mildred St, El Monte, CA 91731</a></p><div class="mobilehideme">[flat_button text="Directions" url="" padding="5px 10px" bg_color="#ffffff" border_color="#d80000" border_width="1px" text_color="#d80000" text_size="12px" font-weight="800" target="_self"][flat_button text="View Classes" url="" padding="5px 10px" bg_color="#d80000" border_color="#FFFFFF" border_width="1px"  text_color="#ffffff" text_size="12px" font-weight="800" target="_self"]</div><hr class="hrmobile">


<h3>Corona</h3><p><a href="https://www.google.com/maps?ll=33.884507,-117.564539&z=11&t=m&hl=en-US&gl=US&mapclient=embed&daddr=Circle+City+Center+365+N+Main+St+Corona,+CA+92880@33.8845072,-117.5645389" target="_blank">365 N. Main St, Corona, CA 92880</a></p><div class="mobilehideme">[flat_button text="Directions" url="" padding="5px 10px" bg_color="#ffffff" border_color="#d80000" border_width="1px" text_color="#d80000" text_size="12px" font-weight="800" target="_self"][flat_button text="View Classes" url="" padding="5px 10px" bg_color="#d80000" border_color="#FFFFFF" border_width="1px"  text_color="#ffffff" text_size="12px" font-weight="800" target="_self"]</div><hr class="hrmobile">[/one_third_last]
[/content_block]

[content_block bg_image="" max_bg_width="yes" bg_fixed="no" bg_position="center center" bg_repeat="repeat-x" parallax_scroll="no" bg_color="#293037" content_padding="100px 0 80px" font_color="#FFFFFF"]
   
<div style="text-align:center; max-width:775px; margin:0 auto 0;">
 <h4 style="margin-bottom: 25px;font-size: 36px; color: #fff; line-height: 1.2; font-weight: bold; text-align:center;">CPR & First Aid Certification Classes</h4>
<p style="margin-bottom: 20px; font-size: 17px; color: #FFFFFF; text-align:center;">CPR Training Professionals offers daily CPR certification and First Aid classes at our conveniently located training centers. Additionally we provide on-site training for businesses and groups throughout Southern California including Orange County, Los Angeles, San Bernardino, San Diego and Riverside County.</p>


</div>
[/content_block]


[content_block bg_image="" max_bg_width="yes" bg_fixed="no" bg_position="center center" bg_repeat="repeat-x" parallax_scroll="no" bg_color="#fff" content_padding="100px 0 80px" font_color="#d80000"]
   <div style="text-align: center;">


        <h4 style="margin-bottom: 25px;"><span style="font-size: 36px; color: #d80000; line-height: 1.2; font-weight: bold;">Our Corporate Clients</span> </h4></div>

<div style="text-align: center;">
[one_half]
<div style="text-align: center;"><img src="https://www.cprtrainingpro.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/client-logo-7.png" alt="Client Logos"></div>[/one_half]
[one_half_last]
<div style="text-align: center;"><img src="https://www.cprtrainingpro.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/client-logo-8.png" alt="Client Logos"></div>[/one_half_last]
</div>

<div style="text-align: center;">
[one_half]
<div style="text-align: center;"><img src="https://www.cprtrainingpro.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/client-logo-9.png" alt="Client Logos"></div>[/one_half]
[one_half_last]
<div style="text-align: center;"><img src="https://www.cprtrainingpro.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/client-logo-10.png" alt="Client Logos"></div>[/one_half_last]
</div>



[/content_block]




[content_block bg_image="" max_bg_width="yes" bg_fixed="no" bg_position="center center" bg_repeat="repeat-x" parallax_scroll="no" bg_color="#d80000" content_padding="100px 0 80px" font_color="#d80000"]
   <div style="text-align: center;">
        <h4 style="margin-bottom: 25px;"><span style="font-size: 36px; color: #fff; line-height: 1.2; font-weight: bold;">Here's what others are saying:</span> </h4></div>


[one_third]
<blockquote><p style="color:#fff;">We have been using CPR Training Professionals for over 10 years for our staff CPR and First Aid training. The instructors are very friendly and make the class enjoyable.
    <div style="float:right; text-align:right; font-style:normal; font-weight:bold; color:#fff;">
        - Adam Feld</p>
        <a title="Go to http://www.example.com" href="http://www.example.com" target="_blank">http://www.example.com</a>
    </div>
</blockquote>
[/one_third]
[one_third]
<blockquote><p style="color:#fff;">I had a great experience getting my BLS certification with CPR Training Professionals. The class was fast and efficient, and my instructor was extremely knowledgeable.
    <div style="float:right; text-align:right; font-style:normal; font-weight:bold; color:#fff;">
        - Mari Gordan</p>
        <a title="Go to http://www.example.com" href="http://www.example.com" target="_blank">http://www.example.com</a>
    </div>
</blockquote>
[/one_third]
[one_third_last]
<blockquote><p style="color:#fff;">My instructor was awesome. The training was simple, straight forward and I got CPR certified in less than 1 hour. I highly recommend CPR Training Professionals.
    <div style="float:right; text-align:right; font-style:normal; font-weight:bold; color:#fff;">
        - Jim Stevens</p>
        <a title="Go to http://www.example.com" href="http://www.example.com" target="_blank">http://www.example.com</a>
    </div>
</blockquote>
[/one_third_last]
[/content_block]
```

Answer (score 0):

This in your CSS should do:

```
#page-content {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code you have a lot of overflows on the main wrapper. Try this code below

```
body #wrapper-1 {
    overflow-x: visible;
}
```